# How to install older versions of CUDA in conda environment?

Tags: tensorflow, conda

I've been struggling to install an older version of CUDA in a conda environment. In practice, I need to install TensorFlow 1.14 and CUDA 8.0, with the nvcc compiler.

This is what I've tried:

```
conda create -n tf114-cuda8 tensorflow-gpu=1.14 cudatoolkit=8.0 python=3.6
source activate tf114-cuda8
```

At this point, nvcc is not available, because it is not included with default conda installation. Thus, I ran:

```
conda install -c conda-forge nvcc_linux-64=9.2
```

..but nothing! Now I have nvcc under the environment directory: `~/venvs/conda/miniconda3/envs/tf114-cuda8/`, but it seems it is not the right one? In fact, if I do:

```
nvcc-version
```

it returns:

> nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA
> Corporation Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019 Cuda compilation
> tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243

What has gone wrong? Why is the nvcc version the 10.1? how can I install TensorFlow 1.14 with CUDA 8.0 and nvcc included?

Comment: Why do you imagine that "nvcc_linux-64=9.2" would select CUDA 8?

Comment: In practice, I want nvcc for cuda 8.0, but I cannot use `conda-forge nvcc_linux-64=8.0` (the older available version is 9.2). So, I imagined that maybe 9.2 and 8.0 were compatible... I don't have other ideas on how to get nvcc installed in this conda environment. Any suggestion? :)

Comment: Why do you wish to use CUDA 8.0?  The reason I ask is that a common reason people try to use that particular old version of CUDA is that it is the last one that supported cc2.x devices.  If that is your intent, you're going to have trouble anyway, because Tensorflow has never worked with a cc2.x device, regardless of the software install.

Comment: Hi @RobertCrovella :) thanks for your help. I wish to install CUDA 8 because I need to run old code which was working with older versions of CUDA. If I'm not wrong, it was CUDA 8 (or otherwise it was an even older version of CUDA!). Unfortunately, the code does not work with CUDA > 8 (see this repo for other info: https://github.com/MiguelMonteiro/CRFasRNNLayer , and this issue: https://github.com/MiguelMonteiro/permutohedral_lattice/issues/25 )

Comment: I think its unlikely that simply switching to CUDA 8 will resolve your issue, and I believe the inability to find `cuda_runtime.h` really has no bearing on what CUDA version you are using but rather the nature of your CUDA install (broken vs. not broken).   There shouldn't be any need to switch to CUDA 8 to resolve that issue.  But I do agree its about getting a proper development environment for CUDA set up inside conda, if you need to work in a conda environment.   Good luck!

Comment: Dear @RobertCrovella, thank you for your insight on this... Working in conda would be better for me. However, as a plan B, is there any way to get the needed compiler outside the conda environment, but _without_ altering the current system configuration? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I know it's not your question, but I had more success using docker to reproduce different environment with different cuda versions. If that is an option I can point out to some resources.

Comment: @OddNorg thanks for the help. Can you share these resources, please?

Comment: @gab there is a example here of a docker file using cuda 9 to compile tensorlfow 1.2 

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/yochze/3898e1405bb3a024acfb9bb9eef132c3/raw/6b057bd8745b0fb8b6fb367b9198a8aaf3784b40/Dockerfile

You can check official nvidia docker for old cuda images.  Here is a tutorial : https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-compile-tensorflow-1-12-on-ubuntu-16-04-using-docker-6ca2d60d7567

Comment: @gab Also notice there are cuda 8 images available on  dokerhub https://hub.docker.com/layers/nvidia/cuda/8.0-cudnn6-devel-ubuntu16.04/images/sha256-76f65aa848f7745a4365c2424ee33230b49b84b5b92ebccacbc0444e526c54a4?context=explore

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @gab, Is your issue resolved now? Else, can you try `conda create -n tf-gpu-cuda8 tensorflow-gpu==1.14 cudatoolkit=9.0`.Thanks!

Comment: Hi @TFer2 Thanks for your help :) unfortunately, I've never been able to solve this... But the command you suggest would install cudatoolkit 9.0, while I'd like to have cuda 8. Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: @gab, according to [Tensorflow Installation Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu), for `TF 1.14` compatible `CUDA` version is `10.0` and to use `CUDA 8.0` in order to accomplish your task, the compatible tensorflow version is `1.4`. Thanks!